# Calculate distance between latitude and longitude using MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, mapkit

Am trying to calculate distance from one point to another. I am able to find method for that.

```
CLLocationDistance dist = [loc distanceFromLocation:loc2];
```

But what it does is calculate distance in a straight line.

What I want is to calculate distance by roadways.

For Example: Lets say If i give from address as Home and To address as Work. I want the distance between Home to Work by roadways. By roadways I get 750meters. But if i calculate by the method distanceFromLocation I get only 400meters.
Can someone help me with an example to calculate distance.

Comment: Please See This Example https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-13-route-directions-with-mapkit

Comment: best Easy Example http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Ill check right now

Comment: I think these are the things I want MKDirections and MKDirectionsRequest. I tried using the calculateDirectionWithCompletionHandler. My response getting error.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625950/estimated-time-between-two-locations-in-ios/35628434#35628434

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pointACoordinate = [pointAAnnotation coordinate];
CLLocation *pointALocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:pointACoordinate.latitude longitude:pointACoordinate.longitude];  

CLLocationCoordinate2D pointBCoordinate = [pointBAnnotation coordinate];
CLLocation *pointBLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:pointBCoordinate.latitude longitude:pointBCoordinate.longitude];  

float distanceMeters = [pointALocation distanceFromLocation:pointBLocation];
float distanceMiles = (distanceMeters / 1609.344);
```

Here pointAAnnotation & pointBAnnotation are the two Annotations which you need to calculate distance between them.

Ref : [Distance bw two Latitude & Longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073183/4014369)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to calculate distance between two location by road ways. The distanceFromLocation: will draw a straight path between two locations and give that distance right? 
Lets say If i give from address as Home and to address as work. I want the distance between from Home to Work by roadways. By roadways I get 750meters. But if i calculate distanceFromLocation I get only 400meters.

Comment: Yes.. this will return direct Straight line length. Better you try with google Api to get exact Distance